# Firebase push notification not working on ios but works on android react native: How to configure react native firebase ios push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

Hi Firebase push notification not working on the ios side. I am using react native and this is the tutorial I used to set it up on ios https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup. Everything is set up but nothing happens when I send notification from firebase console.
Could it be an issue with the apple push notification service ssl certificate?

Comment: Are you testing on an Emulator? I think for ios it doesn't have notifications you need to connect your phone moreover you need to ask for permission before sending

Comment: I am not testing on an emulator, I am using a real device. How did you implement it? Do you have any guidelines or documentation?

Comment: Any updates on this one? I'm having the same issue